# How to disable proxy settings for System Idle Process?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I'm using a proxy software named V2rayN and I found there are lots of error in it:

```
2022/02/10 10:35:25 tcp:127.0.0.1:11012 rejected  proxy/socks: unknown Socks version: 67
```

I used "netstat -ano" to find the process:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:10808        127.0.0.1:11012        TIME_WAIT       0
```

Then I opened the task manager, find that the process PID: 0 is belongs to "System Idle Process", and I have no issue on another windows PC. Any idea on this? Is there any way to disable proxy settings for "System Idle Process"?

Comment: The idle process is not a normal process and it only has dead connections.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by using command which provided by Microsoft Community/ Answers:

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh winhttp reset proxy
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
```

After the commands finished then restart the computer, the issue gone.

Comment: You saved my day! Long time after an attempt to use v2rayN, I had nasty proxy settings somewhere, mostly invisible, only blocking a specific tool (Docker). Running those commands unblocked the Docker requests to their server (before, it was trying to fetch 127.0.0.1:10809).